# How can I detect scroll outside of flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an idea of an app but I don't know if it's possible to do in flutter. Basically, I want to detect when the user scrolls through their phone outside of the flutter app. Is it something take can be done in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to do that

Comment: Can you explain more about why not (or, at least, give some evidence or citation that it isn't)? Right now, all we have is a random stranger on the Internet claiming that you can't do that.